# Java creating a temp file , deleting a specific string and rename to original

Tags: java, file, text

As the topic states im trying to get a specific string that is usually auto generated into the same string and it seems to work because the temp file is created and the string is replaced with "" but its seems that there is an IOException when it comes to renaming to original when deleting , help please?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Main class to test the Road and Settlement classes
 * 
 * @author Chris Loftus (add your name and change version number/date)
 * @version 1.0 (24th February 2016)
 *
 */
public class Application {

    private Scanner scan;
    private Map map;
    private static int setting;

    public Application() {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        map = new Map();
    }

    private void runMenu() {
        setting = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

    }

    // STEP 1: ADD PRIVATE UTILITY MENTHODS HERE. askForRoadClassifier, save and
    // load provided

    private Classification askForRoadClassifier() {
        Classification result = null;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            valid = false;
            System.out.print("Enter a road classification: ");
            for (Classification cls : Classification.values()) {
                System.out.print(cls + " ");
            }
            String choice = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            try {
                result = Classification.valueOf(choice);
                valid = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                System.out.println(choice + " is not one of the options. Try again.");
            }
        } while (!valid);
        return result;
    }

    private void deleteSettlement() {

        String name;
        int p;
        SettlementType newSetK = SettlementType.CITY;
        int set;
        System.out.println("Please type in the name of the settlement");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type in the population of the settlment");
        p = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type in the number of the type of settlement .");
        System.out.println("1: Hamlet");
        System.out.println("2: Village");
        System.out.println("3: Town");
        System.out.println("4: City");
        set = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if (set == 1) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.HAMLET;
        }

        if (set == 2) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.VILLAGE;
        }

        if (set == 3) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.TOWN;
        }

        if (set == 4) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.CITY;
        }

        String generatedResult = "Name: " + name + " Population: " + p + " SettlementType " + newSetK;

        String status = searchAndDestroy(generatedResult);
    }

    private String searchAndDestroy(String delete) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Pikachu\\workspace\\MiniAssignment2\\settlements.txt");

        try {
            File temp = File.createTempFile("settlement", ".txt", file.getParentFile());

            String charset = "UTF-8";

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));

                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    line = line.replace(delete, "");
                    writer.println(line);

                }
                System.out.println("Deletion complete");
                    reader.close();
                    writer.close();
                file.delete();
                temp.renameTo(file);
            } 



            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Sorry! Can't do that! 1");
            }

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Sorry! Can't do that! 2");
            }


        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Sorry! Can't do that! , IO Exception error incurred 3");
        }


        return null;
    }

    private void save() {
        map.save();
    }

    private void load() {
        map.load();
    }

    public void addSettlement() {
        String name;
        int p;
        SettlementType newSetK = SettlementType.CITY;
        int set;
        System.out.println("Please type in the name of the settlement");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type in the population of the settlment");
        p = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please type in the number of the type of settlement .");
        System.out.println("1: Hamlet");
        System.out.println("2: Village");
        System.out.println("3: Town");
        System.out.println("4: City");
        set = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if (set == 1) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.HAMLET;
        }

        if (set == 2) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.VILLAGE;
        }

        if (set == 3) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.TOWN;
        }

        if (set == 4) {
            newSetK = SettlementType.CITY;
        }

        new Settlement(name, newSetK, p);
    }

    private void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Please type in the number of the action that you would like to perform");
        System.out.println("1: Create Settlement");
        System.out.println("2: Delete Settlement");
        System.out.println("3: Create Road");
        System.out.println("4: Delete Road");
        System.out.println("5:Display Map");
        System.out.println("6:Save Map");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application app = new Application();

        app.printMenu();
        app.runMenu();
        System.out.println(setting);
        if (setting == 1) {
            app.addSettlement();
        }

        if (setting == 2) {
            app.deleteSettlement();
        }
        app.load();
        app.runMenu();
        app.save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note on code quality: such endless if-chains to select an enum ... very bad idea. Instead, you could add an int-taking constructor to your enum class; then you add a method like `getSettlementFor(int selector)`. That method would iterate all enums and check "their int"; and return the matching one. You really really do not want to scatter such "mappings" outside of your enum; you never ever want to have more than one place in your code that does such mapping work!

Comment: Please add stack trace to the question

Comment: @Jägermeister Thanks for the comment on my code quality , thing is im rushing this as it is due in a couple of days and was planning on polishing once its done . I am super new to Java and OOP in general so I don't know how long I'll take exactly

Comment: @Sanjeev Thanks for the comment , I was able to solve my IOException but now it still does not rename the file . any suggestion?

Comment: @YourfavOreo you will surely get it done, just don't rush it, because if you do you will create a bug and not notice & that will leave you leaking

Comment: @YourfavOreo There is one important law of programming reality: **later equals never**. You should **not** focus on "getting it to work" ... to then improve the quality of your code. If you have an eye on quality right from the beginning ... you will find that "getting it work" is actually much easier. But of course I see that such a proposal isn't easy to "just follow" as newbie.

Comment: @Jägermeister Note: Newbie to Java and not to coding in general . I usually use Non-OOP language and usually code for modularity but I do agree, you are right at that standpoint, when I think about it, I don't usually polish the finished program unless efficiency is affected by a huge chunk . For example : Huge Arduino pojects but you are right , I should start coding "Healthy" from the beginning so it becomes a part of me and not just an after thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked if it was deletable (file.delete throws a boolean exception) so I tried deleting it directly via windows and apparently it was being used by java so I assumed eclipsed glitch and upon closing and booting up eclipse again it worked..... well... that was rather anti-climactic .... Thank you so much for the discussion , I would definitely never had figured it out if not for the discussion :D <3 You are all in my heart